# Qual a diferença entre REST API e CRUD?

Tags: express.js, crud

Eu pesquisando sobre REST API percebi que ela é muito parecido com a ideia de CRUD, mas não entendi a diferença. Por enquanto estou com a ideia de que REST API é uma forma moderna de dizer CRUD.

Answer (score -2):

CRUD é um conjunto de operações primitivas (principalmente para bancos de dados e armazenamento de dados estáticos), enquanto o REST é um estilo de API de nível muito alto (principalmente para serviços da Web e outros sistemas "ativos").

O primeiro manipula dados básicos, o outro interage com um sistema complexo.